# Difference between attribute and a column created with ALTER?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am new to SQL. I am confused between 'attribute' and a custom column we create with 'ALTER' .
 For Example:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype
```

Doesn't this 'column_name' be our new attribute in the table ?

Comment: What exactly do you think an "attribute" is? Tables are made of columns - regardless on how that column was created.

Comment: i didnt get you .. i meant is the column_name an attribute of a table ?

Comment: `column_name` is the name of the column.

Comment: Remove the confusion by thinking in terms of two *different* levels: **1** a "logical" model, which describes the entities (people, places, events, concepts and things which can be uniquely identified and we want to store information about), independent of implementation details, and **2** a physical implementation that transforms the logical model into relational database tables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The confusion is due to a difference in the terminology we use for the logical "model" and the database implementation.

In the (logical) Entity Relationship Model (ERM), an "Entity" has "Attributes".

When we implement the model into a relational database, an "attribute" for an "entity" gets stored as a "column" in a "table".

In the (implemented) relational database, a "table" contains "columns".

We add *attributes* to entities; we add *columns* to tables.

(This relates to the standard relational model, and disregards any discussion of implementing an Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) model in the database.)

---

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE order
  ADD COLUMN date_received DATETIME ;
```

This is adding a column, with a column name of `date_received` to the `order` table.

We add the column, because in the logical model, the "Order" entity has an attribute of "date received".

Answer (score 3):

The Entity-Relationship design discipline covers "entities" that have "attributes."  The physical-level RDBMS design discipline covers "table" and "columns."  An entity -- a person -- might have an attribute of "given name".  The corresponding table would be called `person` in an RDBMS, and it would have a column called `given_name`.

Entities and columns are the same thing in slightly different kinds of jargon.